# uboot crash at higher level gcc and kernel header

Tags: gcc, u-boot

I m using gcc 4.2.4 to compile uboot and the uboot works fine. But however when I m using gcc 4.3.5, the uboot image crashed at the very beginning part. Any idea of how can I debug? Or which part should I look up to debug? It crashed at:

```
#define ath_reg_wr(_phys, _val) do { \
ath_reg_wr_nf(_phys, _val); \
ath_reg_rd(_phys); \


#define ath_reg_wr_nf(_phys, _val) \
((*(volatile ath_reg_t *)KSEG1ADDR(_phys)) = (_val))
```

I have no idea how compiler can affect the crash.

Comment: Did you try cleaning everything and rebuilding? You may have different parts compiled using different compilers.

Comment: Try to do a "make mrproper" first. If you follow the u-boot mailing list you would be aware that some compiler and code combination yeild a broken binary. What platform do you have? What version of u-boot? Suggestions ... Try to use the ELDK compilers from ftp://ftp.denx.de/pub/eldk/ Also as a rule of thumb, I try not to use very new gcc compilers specially if I'm maintaining old u-boot code.

Comment: Yes, I did clean the previous build. It's U-Boot 1.1.4.54. It's MIPS platform

Comment: I found it crashed at PCI and SPI write commands . Both buses write instruction call "ath_reg_wr"

Comment: It crashed at below:#define ath_reg_wr(_phys, _val) do { \
ath_reg_wr_nf(_phys, _val); \
ath_reg_rd(_phys); \ 


#define ath_reg_wr_nf(_phys, _val) \
((*(volatile ath_reg_t *)KSEG1ADDR(_phys)) = (_val))

Comment: @georgewhr "It's U-Boot 1.1.4.54" <-- Archaic! So what is your KSEG1ADDR? Is it a valid address? Also, is the corresponding write access aligned correctly?

Comment: @sessyargc.jp, thanks for the reply. The src code I compiled is same, how does different version of gcc could affect the alignment issue? I just don't know where should I look it up. Is there a flag argument I can set in gcc?

Comment: @georgewhr you should read the gcc mailing lists. Did your u-boot boot up correctly using old gcc versions? As I mentioned previously try to use older ELDK compilers.

Comment: @sessyargc.jp,  yes, it works with older version of gcc, which is 4.2.4.

Comment: @georgewhr Say the answer myself in the original post .. silly me. Why do you want to use 4.3.5 in the first place given that the old compiler works? Create a binary using gcc 4.2.4, then create another binary using 4.3.5. Disassemble both binaries. Check the assembler mnemonics used. You should start there if you want to continue this endeavor.

Comment: @sessyargc.jp, yes, I disassemble the object file and compare the crashed one and worked one, they looks same at the crash point...

Comment: @georgewhr if you can check the values in the registers that would be good too. Use a debugger or a JTAG.

Comment: the problem was solved, there should be fpic flag added